# Good word/phrase for crazy?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, usage, expressions

The context is like "He'll probably think I'm crazy." The expressions I see mostly are 頭がおかしい and 気が狂う. I've also seen イカれる be used, but I've heard that's really slangy. Are there better expressions to use than these and is there a difference in nuance between these expressions?

Comment: What meaning of crazy are you asking about in particular? Actually mentally ill? Or perhaps, not literally mentally ill, but out of control or extremely agitated? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. Not mentally ill but like someone is overly worried or paranoid about something and someone makes a comment like "quit being so crazy."

Comment: Why don't you edit that into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"どうかしてる", or "どうかしている"